# Android 12 Downloadmanager freezes

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-download-manager, android-12

DownloadManager suddenly **freezes** and stops working for 15-20 min. Downloads remain queued. The weird thing is that it only happens on Android 12 on both physical device and emulator. But on `Andorid 13 and 11` the downloads don't stop. The application still works without any problems. Maximum number of documents to download 112

It's a Worker that passes a list of documents to `DownloadManager` via a for loop. and the `registerReceiver()` is declared in the context inside the for loop.

Does anyone else have this problem?

Thank you very much in advance.